# Replace the class of a div after a time delay

Tags: javascript, html

The class of the div should only be removed after a delay. Unfortunately this does not work as in my example. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve that? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    var displaytop = document.getElementById('my_div');
    displaytop.className = displaytop.delay(10000).className.replace('start-top');
});
```

Comment: you can use `setTimeout()` but don't forget that your code will be executed repeatedly while the mouse is being moved

Comment: `mousemove` fires once for every pixel the mouse moves over the element, which would not seem to be a good fit with that you're trying to do. Have you tried `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`? You'll also need to use `setTimeout()`, not `delay()`, as @kosmos mentioned

Comment: You can use this: `classList.toggle('start-top');` Yet consider other comments too. You should use timeout and debounce method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add jQuery. You can do this with the help of javascript only.
For reference find the fiddle.

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/CHVbb/1465/"
```